# Calculate the cache hit rate

Tags: caching, hit

I need some help with calculating the cache hits/misses in a loop which adds 128 32bit numbers together which are in an array a[i] (0 <= i <= 127).

The cache itself is empty and got 32bytes/row.
Calculate the cache hit rate.

a) with the counter/sum vars being in the storage.
b) with the counter/sum vars being buffered into registers
c) How do the hit rates differ if we would use 16bit numbers instead of 32bit numbers.

I don't know how to calculate the hits/misses in a program. We got an example with multiplication but I somehow don't understand how it works.

[image: blue is the first pass, green the second]

(blue is the first pass, green the second)

Edit:

```
        sum = 0
        j = 0
loop:   read j
        if(j >= 128) exit
        else
        read g[j]
        read sum
        compute sum + g[j]
        write sum
        read j
        compute j+1
        write j
        jump to loop
```

pseudo code for the task

Comment: Which part are you having difficulty with? Calculating the hit ratio? It's just the total number (red) of hits divided by the total number of accesses (hits and misses).

Comment: BTW, you should start by providing an equivalent pseudocode for the problem you're trying to solve (adding 128 numbers together).

Comment: @hayesti I added the pseudo code now. I believe it is correct. My problem is how do I know when my cache gets a miss or a hit in this program? I undertand that in the mul example the first two rows are misses but why is at the row with read g[j] exactly 16 misses?

Comment: and when I find the hit rate what does it mean if the sum and j variable are stored in the storage or buffered in registers? what is the difference and how does it affect the result?

Comment: Good, that's a better start. In the multiplication example you've given, there are 512 elements read from the `g` array. There are _16_ misses and _496_ hits. This suggests that 32 numbers can fit on a cache line/block. We read an element of `g`; it's not in the cache so it's a miss. Afterwards, the line that contains this value _will_ be in the cache and the next 31 values read from `g` will be hits. After 31 hits, the next time `g` is accessed, we will need to access a different line/block so we get another miss. Do you see the pattern?

Comment: BTW, the multiplication example appears to be using 8-bit values. You will have to think about what will happen for 32-bit and 16-bit integers for your sum problem. How many numbers can we fit in a cache line/block then? :-)

Comment: @hayesti thanks alot! 32bit only 8 numbers and 16 bit 16 numbers? this is because 8 bit is one byte right? so all I need to check is for 32bits : 128 numbers/8 rows = 16 misses? but can you tell me what the a) and b) task means? I don't know what the problem is whether they are in the storage or buffered into the register? Edit: so my total misses would be 18? and hits would be 128 + 112 + 128 + 128  + 128 + 128?

Comment: I think you understand better now. I suggest you use the pseudocode you wrote and make a similar table/diagram to multiplication problem. Put the miss/hit of first pass, second pass and then all the passes. The (a) task you already understand, it means loading/storing the variable from/to memory each time. For (b), if you use registers scalar variables like `sum` and `j` don't need to be in memory. You could rename those variable as `reg0` and `reg1` for clarity and make another table/diagram.

Comment: @hayesti that means when I use (b) i can erase all misses/hits for sum/j cause they are in registers am i right?

Comment: Yes, that's right. You can remove the read/write `j` and `sum` since it's implicit now.